# How to set the minDate, setDate, defaultDate for datepicker from a different datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 2 date pickers "a range" first picker is the "pre_from" date and the second one is the "pre_to" date. However, what I would like to do here is to sent the "pre_to" picker minDate to = the "pre_from" selecteDate. Also I would like to set the "pre_to" picker to have the last day of the "pre_from" selected month.

I have added a code to the "onClose" function of the "pre_from" datepicker that should set the "pre_to." But it is not working as I expected. For some reason it does not set the default select date, and the currently selected value.

Below id what I have tried.

```
$(function(){

function LastDayOfMonth(Year, Month) {
    return new Date( (new Date(Year, Month+1,1))-1 );
}


    $('#pre_from').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            var d = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd",  selectedDate);
            var last_day = LastDayOfMonth(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth());

                //setDate: new Date(last_day.getFullYear(), last_day.getMonth(), last_day.getDay() ),
                //defaultDate: new Date(last_day.getFullYear(), last_day.getMonth(), last_day.getDay() )

            $( "#pre_to" ).datepicker({ 
                minDate: selectedDate,
                setDate: last_day,
                defaultDate: last_day
            }); 
        }   
    });

    $('#pre_to').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#pre_from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }       
    }); 

});
```

What am I doing wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally

I had to change  `$( "#pre_to" ).datepicker({` to    `$( "#pre_to" ).datepicker("option", {`

```
$(function(){

function LastDayOfMonth(Year, Month) {
    return new Date( (new Date(Year, Month+1,1))-1 );
}


    $('#pre_from').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            var d = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd",  selectedDate);
            var last_day = LastDayOfMonth(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth());

            $( "#pre_to" ).datepicker("option", { 
                minDate: selectedDate,
                setDate: last_day,
                defaultDate: last_day
            }); 
        }   
    });

    $('#pre_to').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#pre_from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }       
    }); 

});
```